# Can't import .json file to Firebase database.x

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to import my json file (called users.json), this is the file content:

```
{
  users:{

  },
  friends:{

  }
}
```

I'm trying to import it to the firebase but it says "invalid json file".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to import json too, but can't find the option. Can you help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every key in JSON file has to be surrounded by quotation marks.

```
{
  "users":{

  },
  "friends":{

  }
}
```

Comment: I will, as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

A JSON File shoul look like this:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "UID1" : {
      "userEmail" : "name1@email,com",
      "userName" : "name1",
    },
    "UID2" : {
      "userEmail" : "name2@email,com",
      "userName" : "name2",
    },
  },
    "friends" : {
    //
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, How can I automatically add user UID and nickname to the database after signup? I tried using this writeUserData but without any luck.https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: I get the uid, name and so on from Firebase authentication.